# Expectation and functional analysis.

Tags: probability, functional-analysis

Let $X$ be a random variable which takes values $L^2$ functions ($f : I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$, with $I$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^p$). Let $f_{0} : I\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$ be a function such that 
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}[X(s) - f_{0}(s)] = 0,
\end{equation}
for all $s\in I$.
My question is whether or not
\begin{equation}\nonumber
\text{E}\left[\cfrac{X(s) - f_0(s)}{\|X - f_{0}\|_{L^2}}\right] = 0
\end{equation}
for all $s\in I,$ where $\|\cdot\|_{L^2}$ is the $L^2$ norm.

I have the intuition that it is true.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Isn't it true because of the linearity of the expectation?

Comment: @Botond $\|X - f_0\|_{L^2}$ is itself a random variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, this need not be true. For simplicity let $I = [0,1]$ and let $f_0 = 0$. Let $X$ be a random variable such that with probability $\frac13$, $X(s) = 2$ for all $s \in [0,1]$ and with probability $\frac23$, $X(s) = -1$ for all $s \in [0,1]$.

Then $\mathbb{E}[X(s)] = 0$ for all $s \in [0,1]$ but 
$$\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{X(s)}{\|X\|_{L^2([0,1])}} \right ] = \frac13 - \frac23 = - \frac13.$$